# Gitlab runner + autoscaling + scaled runner options

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using gitlab runner with `docker+machine` executor to fire up autoscaled runners on AWS. I would like to use docker-in-docker setup inside the runners to build containers, but I can't find out how to define the needed `[runners.docker]` properties for the spawned runners to enable docker usage.

Is it possible to somehow pass some config info to autoscaled runners?

Answer (score 1):

you just need this in your config.toml of your autoscale runner:

```
[runners.docker]
  privileged = true
```

I use docker-in-docker to build my own php containers for testing and store them in gitlabs registry. see https://gitlab.cwd.at/docker/php/builds/21582 for a build example and https://gitlab.cwd.at/docker/php/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml for the build definition

see here my current config - its using S3 for caching and digitalocean for the runners:

```
concurrent = 10

[[runners]]
  name = "ec2-autoscale-runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.mydomain.at/ci"
  token = "12345"
  executor = "docker+machine"
  limit = 10
  environment = ["COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR=/cache"]
  [runners.machine]
    OffPeakPeriods = [               # Set the Off Peak time mode on for:
      "* * 0-9,18-23 * * mon-fri *", # - Monday to Friday for 12am to 9am and 6pm to 11pm
      "* * * * * sat,sun *"          # - whole Saturday and Sunday
    ]
    OffPeakIdleCount = 0             # There must be 1 machine in Idle state - when Off Peak time mode is on
    OffPeakIdleTime = 3550           # Each machine can be in Idle state up to 1200 seconds (after this it will be removed) - when Off Peak time mode is on
    IdleCount = 0                    # There must be 5 machines in Idle state - when Off Peak time mode is off
    IdleTime = 3550                  # Each machine can be in Idle state up to 600 seconds (after this it will be removed) - when Off Peak time mode is off
    MaxBuilds = 100                    # Each machine can handle up to 100 builds in a row (after this it will be removed)
    MachineName = "auto-scale-%s"    # Each machine will have a unique name ('%s' is required)
    MachineDriver = "digitalocean"   # Docker Machine is using the 'digitalocean' driver
    MachineOptions = [
        "digitalocean-image=21937863",
        #"digitalocean-image=20969606",
        "digitalocean-access-token=12345",
        "digitalocean-region=fra1",
        "digitalocean-size=4gb",
        "digitalocean-private-networking",
        "digitalocean-ipv6=true"
    ]
  [runners.ssh]
    user = "root"
    identity_file = "/etc/gitlab-runner/id_rsa"
  [runners.docker]
    privileged = true
  [runners.cache]
    Type = "s3"
    ServerAddress = "s3.amazonaws.com"
    AccessKey = "1234"
    SecretKey = "1234"
    BucketName = "cwd-gitlab-cache"
    BucketLocation = "eu-central-1"
    Insecure = false
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'll try once again with your advice.

Comment: @jamie-wilson I forgot to test this and after all we decided to roll out a DIY solution on AWS that relies on CPU load meters to do autoscaling. Quite a work, but works nicely now.

Comment: What does the `IdleCount` means in here?

Comment: @JananathBanuka how many idle runner machines are allowed to be present. so you can for example have 1 machine running at all times.